# .net frameworkの代わりの.net core 3.0 class library project の作成方法

Tags: c#

表題の通りですが、.NetFrameworkではなく.NetCoreのClass Libraryのプロジェクトの新規作成が見当たらないのですが、作成できるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2019のVisual Studio Installerの「ワークロード」で「.NET Core クロスプラットフォームの開発」と、「個別のコンポーネント」で「.NET Core 3.0 SDK」がチェックされているのを確認して更新すれば使えるようになるのでは？
[Visual Studio のインストール](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)
[Visual Studio を最新リリースに更新する](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/install/update-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)
[ワークロードやコンポーネントを追加または削除することで Visual Studio を変更する](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/install/modify-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)

Visual Studio 2017以前やWindows以外のMSBuild等での作成ならば、「Download .NET Core 3.0」のページからSDKやRuntimeをダウンロード・インストールすれば良いと思われます。
[Download .NET Core 3.0](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0) あるいは [Download .NET](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download)

こんな風に出てきます。フレームワークの版数は入っている最新になると思われます。プロジェクトを作った後にプロパティで確認・変更できます。
[image: VS2019 New Project]

---

**追記**
ちなみに調べていたらこんな記述があったので、Visual Studio 2017以前のIDEでは .NET Core 3.0 関連は扱えないようです。Visual Studio 2019に上げるか、SDKのCLIでやるしかないようですね。

[.NET Standard 2.1 - .NET Core 3.0 の新機能](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#net-standard-21)

> Visual Studio を使用している場合、Visual Studio 2017 では **.NET Standard 2.1** または **.NET Core 3.0** がサポートされていないため、[Visual Studio 2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ja/downloads/) が必要です。

CLIによるプロジェクトの作成は、ここで解説されています。
まだ 3.0 の記述は追加されていません。
[dotnet new コマンド - .NET Core CLI](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new?tabs=netcore22)

クラスライブラリ作成は `dotnet new classlib` が基本ですね。
その後ろにオプション類を追加します。

以下の英語の記事に、3.0 になってからのカスタムテンプレートやプロジェクト作成の解説が書かれています。
いずれはこの記事が日本語化されたり、Microsoftサイトの文書が更新されるでしょう。
[Using the .Net Core Template Engine to Create Custom Templates and Projects](https://www.infoq.com/articles/dotnet-core-template-engine/)

Comment: .NET Core クロスプラットフォームの開発をインストールしたら出てきました。回答ありがとうございました。